# I want range for specific value in excel as

Tags: excel

I want range for specific value in excel as,

my values in column A

```
122.7 
250.6
377.9
507.1
635.3
761.1
892.7
1021.5
1154.7
1284.7
```

my values in column B

```
50 
100
150
200
250
300
350
400
450 
500
```

I have to compare value is 533 in A column. If 533 is value then it should return range 507.1 and 635.3 in separate row for further calculations. (e.g Similarly I input value is 210 then it should return range 122.7 and 250.6 in separate row.)

for further calculations,value which we got from above 507.1 and 635.3 should take value from Corresponding column B i.e value of 200 and 250 in separate row (e.g value which we got 122.7 and 250.6 should take value from Corresponding column B i.e value of 50 and 100 )

Comment: How does this differ from your problem you just posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48703138/it-is-regarding-in-excel-to-get-get-value-with-comparison

Answer (score 1):

Considering your Lookup value is in `D1`,
Put this formula in `E1` to get upper range

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(D1,A:A,1)+1)
```

and this formula in `F1` to get the lower range

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(D1,A:A,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

c1 = Enter the search value

Formula in C2
`=INDEX($A$2:$B$11,MATCH(INDEX($A$2:$A$11,MATCH(C1,$A$2:$A$11,1)),$A$2:$A$11,0),2)`

Formula in D2
`INDEX($A$2:$B$11,MATCH(INDEX($A$2:$A$11,MATCH(C1,$A$2:$A$11,1)+1),$A$2:$A$11,0),2)`

[image]